# Excel very long IF AND nested formula not working

Tags: excel

I want to look in B4 for a 1 or a 0, if its a 1 i would like to use the formula up to "value if true" 133, if its a zero i would like to use the formula after 133. The formula after 133 works alone.

I appreciate it is very ugly.

> =IF(B4>0,IF($E$3-$B$3<=124,25,IF(AND($E$3-$B$3<=365,$E$3-$B$3>125),25,(IF(AND($E$3-$B$3<730,$E$3-$B$3>365),50,IF(AND($E$3-$B$3<1095,$E$3-$B$3>730),75,IF(AND($E$3-$B$3<1460,$E$3-$B$3>1095),100,IF(AND($E$3-$B$3>2920,$E$3-$B$3<5110),111,IF(AND($E$3-$B$3>5110,$E$3-$B$3<7300),122,IF(AND($E$3-$B$3>7300),133,if(and($E$3-$B$3<=124,25,IF(AND($E$3-$B$3<=365,$E$3-$B$3>125),25,(IF(AND($E$3-$B$3<730,$E$3-$B$3>365),50,IF(AND($E$3-$B$3<1095,$E$3-$B$3>730),75,IF(AND($E$3-$B$3<1460,$E$3-$B$3>1095),100,IF($E$3-$B$3>1460,100,)))))))))))))))))

---

Comment: What is the exact logic behind the formula? This seems like it can be simplified by use of `VLOOKUP`.

Comment: I am looking up allowances for teachers' leave days, based on their time in tenure.So looking between dates of start E3 and todays date B3, then based on how long they have been a teacher influences their leave allowance. The problem is that there are 2 authorities, in this case 1 and 0, if they are 1, there are far more levels of allowance. Unfortunately i cannot  yet post my spreadsheet due to my small number of posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had an `AND` statement, with only one argument just before the `113` result. Try this instead:

```
=IF(B4>0,IF($E$3-$B$3<=124,25,IF(AND($E$3-$B$3<=365,$E$3-$B$3>125),25,(IF(AND($E$3-$B$3<730,$E$3-$B$3>365),50,IF(AND($E$3-$B$3<1095,$E$3-$B$3>730),75,IF(AND($E$3-$B$3<1460,$E$3-$B$3>1095),100,IF(AND($E$3-$B$3>2920,$E$3-$B$3<5110),111,IF(AND($E$3-$B$3>5110,$E$3-$B$3<7300),122,IF(AND($E$3-$B$3>7300),133,IF($E$3-$B$3<=124,25,IF(AND($E$3-$B$3<=365,$E$3-$B$3>125),25,(IF(AND($E$3-$B$3<730,$E$3-$B$3>365),50,IF(AND($E$3-$B$3<1095,$E$3-$B$3>730),75,IF(AND($E$3-$B$3<1460,$E$3-$B$3>1095),100,IF($E$3-$B$3>1460,100,)))))))))))))))))
```

EDIT2:
Re-organised for two different criteria comparisons:

```
=IF(B4>0,IF($E$3-$B$3<=124,25,IF(AND($E$3-$B$3<=365,$E$3-$B$3>125),25,(IF(AND($E$3-$B$3<730,$E$3-$B$3>365),50,IF(AND($E$3-$B$3<1095,$E$3-$B$3>730),75,IF(AND($E$3-$B$3<1460,$E$3-$B$3>1095),100,IF(AND($E$3-$B$3>2920,$E$3-$B$3<5110),111,IF(AND($E$3-$B$3>5110,$E$3-$B$3<7300),122,IF(AND($E$3-$B$3>7300),133,""))))))))),IF($E$3-$B$3<=124,25,IF(AND($E$3-$B$3<=365,$E$3-$B$3>125),25,(IF(AND($E$3-$B$3<730,$E$3-$B$3>365),50,IF(AND($E$3-$B$3<1095,$E$3-$B$3>730),75,IF(AND($E$3-$B$3<1460,$E$3-$B$3>1095),100,IF($E$3-$B$3>1460,100,""))))))))
```

Comment: It works perfectly for the 1 result but now returns FALSE for a 0.

Comment: I have edited my answer. add the required statement before the last closing bracket to deal with the `0`

Comment: Sorry, i think i have explained it badly. My 1 and 0 are the 2 different authorities that have different leave structures, honestly i wanted it search B4 for either London or Not London but couldn't make it work. It still works for 1 but obviously now returns zero for 0.

Comment: ok, I think i get what you mean. Which part of the forumla is meant to applied for the `B4=0` case? `if(and($E$3-$B$3<=124` onwards?

Comment: Yes, immediately after 133

Comment: See Edit2 in my Answer above. Think it now does what you need?

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much, i'll now take some time to look through and see what i was doing wrong. Again, thanks.

Comment: No problem, IF statement logic can get confusing when you have lots of criteria. If you see in the middle of my formula, i have lots of `)))))))` this is essentially where you need to close the first IF statement for `B4>0` and then start the next IF statement for `B4=0`. If the question is solved, please do mark my response as best answer :)

Comment: I don't think i have enough reputation to either vote or even chat. Rest assured, I am extremely grateful, and if i could i would.

Comment: You should be able to mark your own questions as solved! If you see grey tick mark on the left hand side of my answer, click it. Please do take a look, it helps me out ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you do this with nested `IF` functions then you really don't need to specify the upper and lower bounds for each range. If you address the ranges in order then the previous `IF`s will always exclude some possibilities, e.g. you can use a more economical approach like this:

`=IF(A1>500,"x",IF(A1>300,"y",IF(A1>100,"z","a")))`

That will assign "x" to every value above 500, "y" to every value between 300 and 500, "z" to every value between 100 and 300 and "a" to everything else (values < 100).

....but normally once you go beyond a few `IF`s it's easier to use a tabular approach with some sort of lookup formula. This approach has several advantages; it makes the formula simpler, easier to change or debug and more transparent

For your specific example you can use this approach

[image]

Formula in C4 is

`=INDEX(I3:J10,MATCH(E3-B3,G3:G10),MATCH(B4,I1:J1,0))`

In column G you need to show the lower bound of each band - I think this will give the values you need but in your formula you don't cater for all values, e.g. you have <=124 and >125 so exactly 125 isn't catered for